# Property of generating function involving $I_n(k)$, number of permutations in a set of size $n$ that have $k$ inversions

Tags: permutations, generating-functions

Reading through "sorting and searching"in Donald Knuth The Art of Computer Programming. There's this property I don't get, thought it's said is easy to prove. If

$$
G_n(z) = I_n(0) + I_n(1) z + \ldots = \sum_{k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^k
$$

then we have

$$
G_n(z) = \left(1+ z + \ldots  + z^{n-1} \right) G_{n-1}(z),
$$

I don't have a clue why that is true. Can you tell me why? If not can you just give me an hint?

By $I_n(k)$ we mean the number of permutation that have $k$ inversion, on a set of size $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$G_n(z) 
= \left(1+ z + \ldots  + z^{n-1} \right) G_{n-1}(z)
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k G_{n-1}(z)
$,
I'll derive a recurrence
for the $I_n(k)$.

$G_n(z) 
=  G_{n-1}(z)\dfrac{1-z^n}{1-z}
$
so
$(1-z)G_n(z) 
= (1-z^n) G_{n-1}(z)
$.

$\begin{array}\\
(1-z^m)G_n(z)
&=(1-z^m)\sum_{k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^k\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^k-\sum_{k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^{k+m}\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^k-\sum_{k\geq m} I_n(k-m)z^{k}\\
&=\sum_{m-1 \ge k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^k+\sum_{k\geq m} (I_n(k)-I_n(k-m))z^{k}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
using this with
$m=1$ and $m=n$,

$\sum_{0 \ge k\geq 0} I_n(k)z^k+\sum_{k\geq 1} (I_n(k)-I_n(k-1))z^{k}
=\sum_{n-1 \ge k\geq 0} I_{n-1}(k)z^k+\sum_{k\geq n} (I_{n-1}(k)-I_{n-1}(k-n))z^{k}
$
or
$I_n(0)+\sum_{k\geq 1} (I_n(k)-I_n(k-1))z^{k}
=\sum_{n-1 \ge k\geq 0} I_{n-1}(k)z^k+\sum_{k\geq n} (I_{n-1}(k)-I_{n-1}(k-n))z^{k}
$.

Therefore
$I_n(0) = I_{n-1}(0)$,
$I_n(k)-I_n(k-1)
=I_{n-1}(k)$
for
$1 \le k \le n-1$,
and
$I_n(k)-I_n(k-1)
=I_{n-1}(k)-I_{n-1}(k-n)$
for
$n \le k$.

Now see if you can derive
these recurrences from 
the properties
of permutations.

You can also
derive a recurrence from
$G_n(z) 
=  G_{n-1}(z)\dfrac{1-z^n}{1-z}
$.

Comment: I'm confused, you derived a recurrence for the coefficients given the one I was asking about. Or is there something I'm missing?